# Prototype - addEventListener Click - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, click, prototype, addeventlistener

I need some help with the below code that I wrote, I need to return the element on click but for some reason it sends back the **Window** object and not the **HTMLElement**.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv">Click me!</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   function myP(selector) {
        if (!(this instanceof myP)) {
            return new myP(selector);
        }

        this.elem = document.querySelector(selector);
    }        

    myP.prototype = {
        click : function(objF){
            this.elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
                objF();
                console.log(this); //Returns the Element ( <div id="myDiv"> )
                return this; // Doesn't work
            }, false);
        }
    }

    myP("#myDiv").click(function(){
        console.log(this); // Returns [object Window]

        // I want to return: ( <div id="myDiv"> ) Element here

    });
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems to work in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgtqsxv7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `.call(EXPECTED_CONTEXT)` to pass `EXPECTED_CONTEXT` as `this` in called function.

Try this:

```js
function myP(selector) {
     if (!(this instanceof myP)) {
       return new myP(selector);
     }

     this.elem = document.querySelector(selector);
   }

   myP.prototype = {
     click: function(objF) {
       this.elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
         objF.call(this);
         return this;
       }, false);
     }
   }

   myP("#myDiv").click(function() {
     console.log(this);
   });
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick responses!